# Webpages have black squares which go away on mouse moves over them

Tags: google-chrome, graphics-card, browser

We are trying to figure out at the office why some people are affected by this issue which is the black squares which show when you open the page. They disappear when you move your mouse over them and the content appears. What could the issue be related to? Flash Player? Graphics card? The issue appeared only in several past weeks to those few people who reported. The few people were from our office.

[image]

Comment: Which browser is it? Something like that can happen on firefox with hardware acceleration turned on I think.

Comment: It was Google Chrome for one of the people!